# bash script to run sql query on wordpress db

Tags: php, wordpress, bash

I am having a weird problem. This is a 3 step scenario.

1. I have a code which downloads video on my ftp directory from Youtube from a given Youtube URL
2. So I have a code which issues the background command to bash script which downloads the heavy videos in background (on ftp directory)
3. Now, when the download is completed, the bash script will call a PHP file which updates an entry in a WordPress.

The problem
The video downloads fine on my ftp directory. And the bash script also works fine until calling my PHP file for updating db entry.

Here is my bash script code

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -o $1 --output-document=$2 $3 &
wait
/usr/bin/php ../cron/vids_pending_download.php $4
exit
```

This script is working fine and calls the PHP file which has this code.

```
require('../../wp-config.php');
require('../inc/inc_config.php');

$vid_key = trim($argv[1]);
#$vid_key = '123_video_key';

$sql_get_vids = "SELECT vid_id, vid_name, file_size, vid_usr FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "video_table WHERE vid_name = '".$vid_key."' ";
$vid_info = $wpdb->get_row($sql_get_vids);
if ($vid_info != null) {
echo 'video found';
} else {
echo 'video not found';
}
```

Now the problem is, if I supply a fixed $vid_key to my sql, it works perfect. But if I bring the $vid_key from the array from bash, it brings empty result set. However if I print the sql and paste in phpMyAdmin, it brings the record fine which means the record is there.

Looking for help. Thanks everyone.

Comment: so the bash is passing `$4` to the php - where is that coming from? Have you tried adding `set -x` to the bash script to see what it is actually executing?

Comment: Okay. I am not aware of that $4 and why its there. The bash script was created by my previous developer who is on holidays currently.

Comment: I think you are talking about the two values coming in array. when printed, array's value 1 shows the php file name which is being called. and value 2 shoes the vid_key variable's value.

Comment: The `$4` is the 4th parameter passed to the bash script, which becomes `$arvg[1]` in the script (the vid_key). My question is have you checked that the bash script is actually passing the correct value, either by an `echo`/`set -x` in the bash and/or an `echo` in the php?
It kinda looks like the bash script is being called wrongly. What calls that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The reason was the bash script was coming too fast in return and look for the next file. While it was doing that, the actual code which is inserting into db wasn't executed. So therefore the record for the return file was not available.

This issue was happening from the actual file which submits the command to bash file.

Thanks again to all for your help